# Application not working after submitting to the play store

Tags: android, android-proguard

When i build and when i signed apk its working fine in my phone but after the upload in google play store something happened and it won't start. Once i open the application i face the error unfortunately app has stopped working! i'm really confused! any suggestion?And i thought this is Pro-guard rules issue can some one suggestion me please.

### Error Log

```
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.karvyinnotech.nba-1.apk
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver
```

### Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.karvyinnotech.nba"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            // shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    //google services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

### proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn org.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration common for all Android apps ----------
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-dump class_files.txt
-printseeds seeds.txt
-printusage unused.txt
-printmapping mapping.txt
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class java.io.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep public class org.apache.commons.io.**
#volley
-keepclasseswithmembernames  interface com.android.volley.** { *; }
-keep class org.json.** {*;}
-keep class android.accounts.**{*;}
-keep class java.io.**{*;}
-keep class android.net.**{*;}
-keep class org.apache.http.**{*;}
-keep class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient{*;}
-keep class com.android.volley.** {*;}
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.** {*;}
-keep class com.android.volley.Response$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.Request$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack$* { *; }
-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$* { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.**
-keep class com.karvyinnotech.nba.models.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }


##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.AppCompatActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.app.IntentService
-keep public class * extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService
-keep public class * extends com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class * implements java.io.Serializable

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}

# Keep subscribe-methods from deletion
-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @com.google.common.eventbus.Subscribe <methods>;
}



# ================ Google Play Services ================
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
# ======================================================

#-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
#    public static <fields>;
#}

-ignorewarnings
```

Comment: It is because of proguard, Try with:-keep public class com.google.**

Comment: Update your firebase-core library to 16.0.4

Answer (score 0):

I suggest put following tow line in your pro guard file

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```